# Dojo Resize Pie and Spider Chart

Tags: charts, dojo, pie-chart, dojox.charting

How can I resize the pie and spider chart in dojo. For Bar,Columns,Lines and area charts we have resize() function with which one can resize the chart size passing height and width.

There is no such method for Pie or Spider Chart provided. How can this be achieved.

I am trying to maximze the chart to full screen after redering in smalll size on load.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the pie chart contains the method .resize(). You can pass the width and the height, like

```
chart.resize(400,300);
```

Comment: I didnot find this method. Checked Api documentation for dojox/charting/plot2d/Pie .